# Java REGEX for numbers 1 to 100

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a REGEX to accept only numbers between 1-100. It would be great if it accepted everything from 1 to infinity, but that's probably to complex - or impossible.

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) {
return str.matches("-?\\d+(\\.\\d+)?");
}//end boolean.
```

Comment: Why do you want to use regex for this task? Just convert `str` to an `int`, and check for range. That would be far easier.

Comment: @RohitJain as mentioned below, that may cause an exception to be thrown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> It would be great if it accepted everything from 1 to infinity, but that's probably to complex - or impossible.

How about simply `"[1-9]\\d*"`?

This would accept a non-zero digit followed by any sequence of digits. In other words, any positive integer.

Comment: Quick thought, since the input is a String, it might contain a String of 0's on start, like "007", maybe a better answer would be:
`0*[1-9]\\d*`

Answer (score 3):

```
public static boolean isNumeric(String str) throws NumberFormatException {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(str); 
    return i > 0 && i < 100; //Arbitrary numbers within range of int
}
```

Not using regex but this should accomplish the same thing. Turn the string into an integer, then check to see if it is in the range you want.

Comment: This would throw an exception if the string contains a non-numeric character.

Comment: Parsing two times is not necessary, and wrap it in a try catch with the `NumberFormatException` and if at all OP wants to have infinity Integer may overflow.

Comment: Both comments are totally true, this was just a quick and dirty example to get him pointed in a direction that might help. I will edit to fix those problems soon.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be really thorough, you can use `"-?(0|([1-9][0-9]*))\.?[0-9]*"` which should give you all numbers from -infinity to +inifinity. Getting rid of the `-?` will give you all positive numbers. `"0|(-?[1-9][0-9]*)"` should give you all integers from -infinity to +infinity. `"[1-9][0-9]*"` will give you all integers greater than 0.

Comment: Do you know how to limit this to a range including negatives? For example -100 to +100?